# react: timing ajax request in render()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I've read a few similar questions but apparently no solutions.

I'm learning React and building an app which should connect to an API every 10/15 minutes. To connect, I am firing an ajax request. However I need the ajax request to be fired every 10 minutes therefore I'd need some sort of timer. If I call the method fetchData inside the render() method, the ajax request will be called every ~1 second. Even if I put a setTimeout() inside the render, this won't work with the ajax request (but it does work with other actions such as console.log()).

Any idea? Basically I need to continuously repeat the ajax request every 10 minutes without the user to click buttons or interact with the app. The first request should be fired when starting the app. Thanks!

```
fetchData = () => {

    var url = "http://url.json";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success : this.parseResponse,
        error : function(req, err){ console.log('API call failed ' + err); }
    })
}

render(){
    //this.fetchData(); //this works but every 1 second
    setTimeout(() => {
        //this.fetchData(); //this won't work as expected
        console.log("timer"); //this works as expected
    }, 5000)

    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.fetchData}></button> //this works as expected but I don't want this
        </div>
        );
}
```

Comment: You may want to move ```polling``` logic into React render hooks, ie, ```componentDidMount``` etc

Comment: Your ()=>{this.fetchData()} should be delayed by 5s as written.  And render should complete before that happens.  What do you see happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to know that if you are going to interact with an api you need to make the call in the `componentDidMount` method **it's a recommended practice**.

Then for make a continuous call you should use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

```
fetchData = () => {
  var url = "http://url.json";
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: this.parseResponse,
    error: function (req, err) {
      console.log('API call failed ' + err);
    }
  })
}
componentDidMount () {
  // This will be called just once
  this.fetchData()

  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.fetchData()
  }, 10000)
}
componentWillUnmount () {
  // It's necessary to do this otherwise the interval
  // will be executed even if the component is not present anymore. 
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
render () {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

If you call `fetchData` inside the `render` method you are running the risk of entering in an infinite loop because if you update the `state` when the ajax is done (or for any reason) then the `render` will be executed and the `fetchData` method too so this will happen over and over again and to make it worst `fetchData` will be executed in intervals.

Comment: thank you. This works, however now when I run it, the first time it executes is when the timer is expired. I'd need to run it every time I open the app and then every time the timer expires. Would it be a bad practice to use a setTimeout() to run it only the first time and the setInterval for the other times?

Comment: If you call `setTimeout` in `componentDidMount` it will be ok, but let me ask why are you willing to use `setTimeout`? won't be better if you call `fetchData` alone?

Comment: anyway I've improved my answer, regards.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call your `setTimeout` (or `setInterval`) in [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), which only fires once when the component is added to the DOM?  In your render method, you're going to `setTimeout` every time there's a render, which could potentially be caused by other events than your fetch (though you haven't shown enough code to be sure).